# Is every nilpotent linear group triangularizable?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, group-theory

Is it true that every finitely generated nilpotent group of matrices over $\mathbb C$ is conjugated to a subgroup of the upper triangular group?

If yes, what is a reference for that?

Comment: Lie-Kolchin Theorem

Comment: Since the Lie-Kolchin theorem applies to connected groups only it is useless here. (At least the classical version of Lie-Kolchin...)

Comment: Btw, there is a version of Lie-Kolchin theorem for linear unipotent groups. But the elements of a linear nilpotent group do not have to be unipotent.

Comment: I think torsion might give you trouble, but maybe not: over $\mathbb{C}$ you have the Jordan form.

Answer (score 3):

I realized that the answer to my question is NO. Take the quaternion group, realized by
$\pm I, \pm \left(\begin{matrix} i & 0 \\ 0 & -i \end{matrix}\right), \pm \left(\begin{matrix} 0 & 1 \\ -1 & 0 \end{matrix}\right), \pm \left(\begin{matrix} 0 & i \\ i & 0 \end{matrix}\right).$ It is nilpotent but not triangularizable.

Comment: Indeed, a finite triangulizable group over a field of characteristic 0 should be abelian, since a unipotent element will have infinite order, and the only thing left are the diagonal matrices.